# Having trouble learning how to look at individual characters in a string checking for case or digit

Tags: python

I am trying to write a simple password checker for homework assignment, looking for at least one capital, one lower case, one digit, and it needs to be 6 or more chars.

I have searched and searched on here and elsewhere, but either what I read doesn't match our instruction, or the replies are more advanced than myself. Any help I get will be cited as a comment in my assignment.

This is just the part of my code which checks for caps, it only looks at the whole string, not the individual characters and I can't seem to find the solution.

```
    passwd = input('enter password: ') ## we are actually using (sys.agrv) 
                                       ## but I am using this for testing
    character = passwd[0:]
    lcase_bad = False
    for character in passwd:
    if not character.islower() > 1:
    lcase_bad = True

    if lcase_bad:
      print('Password must include lowercase letters ')
    else:
        print('password accepted')
```

Comment: Question is not clear, to me, atleast.

Comment: Well to start off with, you should fix your indentation. `passwd[0:]` is just the same as `passwd`. In Python, you don't need to see if a return value is greater than 1, simply check for the truth value `if not character.islower()`. You should also use [`all()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#all)

Comment: @BurhanKhalid `passwd[0:]` is not the same as `passwd`, but the same as `passwd[:]`.  It creates a copy.

Comment: @Hyperboreus it won't actually create a copy for a string, because strings are immutable. They are the same. You can check their memory addresses with `id()`.

Comment: I was referring to it in the context of the OP's snippet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`for character in passwd:`

Here you're iterating through each letter of the input.

When you do `if not character.islower() > 1:`, it will always be True. `.islower()` returns either `True` or `False`, depending on if the string is a capital letter or not. `not False == 1`, because boolean is a subclass of int. `not True == 0`. Both are not greater than one.

---

You can just do something like:

```
capital = False
lowercase = False
number = False
if len(passwd) < 6:
    print 'That was not more than 6 characters'
else:
    for character in passwd:
        if character.islower(): 
            lowercase = True
        elif character.isupper():
            capital = True
        elif character.isdigit():
            number = True
        if capital and lowercase and number:
            break
    else: 
        print 'That did not have a capital letter, lowercase letter, and a digit'
```

Of course this is useful if you want to tell the person what the password *didn't* have. However, you can also just do one test instead.

Comment: Haidro, I like and understand your logic. Thank you. To expand on the problem... if you are willing... if passwd entered is "wheelBarrow" it should print('Password must contain at least 1 digit' ) if "1234567" it should print('Password must contain at least 1 capital letter' ) and print('Password must contain at least one lowercase letter' ) if "r2Dto" ('Password must contain at least 6 digits' ) and if "---!!!---" print('Password must contain at least 1 digit') print('Password must contain at least 1 capital' ) print('Password must contain at least one lowercase' )

Comment: It seems like it should be something like:
        for character in passwd:
        if character.islower(): #for example
            capital = True
            print('Password must contain at least one capital' )
        elif....

Comment: @user2850989 At the end of the for-loop, check `if not capital:` if this runs then there was no capital letter. You can do this for the others (`lowercase` and `number`)

Comment: I got it! I dont seem to be able to give rep vote yet but you have my eternal gratitude, thank you!

Comment: @user2850989 Great to hear!

Answer (score 3):

Just check for all those conditions one after another:

```
mystring = input("enter password: ")
if any(c.isupper() for c in mystring) \    # There is an uppercase letter
and any(c.islower() for c in mystring) \   # There is a lowercase letter
and any(c.isdigit() for c in mystring) \   # There is a number
and len(mystring) > 5:                     # The length is 6 or greater
    # string passed all tests
else:
    # One or more tests failed--input is bad.
```

Comment: I think, it will be better to check all these with a single loop.

Comment: `string` is a poor choice for a variable name.

Answer (score 1):

You've almost got it! If you remove the `> 1` from your code (which won't really do anything useful), you get this:

```
lcase_bad = False
for character in passwd:
    if not character.islower():
        lcase_bad = True
```

It just happens that this will test to see if the entire string is made of lowercase letters. If it is, `lcase_bad` will remain `False`; otherwise, it will become `True`. It should not be an extreme leap of faith to see that if you flip the `False` and `True` around and call it `lcase_good`, you can see whether at least one character is lowercase.

As iCodez notes, you can also rewrite it using `any` with a generator comprehension. It reads fairly easily:

```
if any(character.islower() for character in passwd):
```

However, you probably haven't gotten to generator comprehensions, so it might be best to stay with a `for` loop for clarity's sake.

Comment: icktoofay, I felt like I was close, I am going to experiment with this, thankyou! how do I give + rep?

Comment: @user2850989: You can accept an answer and/or upvote it. You can upvote (with the up arrow) as many answers as you like to indicate they're helpful. You can *accept* an answer with the checkmark on the side to indicate that it *best* answered your question, but only one answer can be accepted at a time. At the moment, I think you only have enough reputation to accept answers, but as time goes on, you'll be able to upvote, too.